# Is it possible for telegram bot to get messages from channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I added bot to channel as administrator but I have no messages in `bot.on('message'` callback. I have no problems with groups add bot privacy disabled. How to get upcoming channel messages?

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
let bot = new TelegramBot('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {polling: true});

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(`${msg.from.username}:  ${msg.text} ${msg.location}`);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you can see in the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#update) the right attribute of update is "channel_post" and not "message"